# Python3 - Error posting data to a stikked instance

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a Python 3 (3.5) script that will act as a simple command line interface to a user's [stikked](https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked) install. The API is pretty straight forward, and its documentation is [available](http://paste.scratchbook.ch/api).

My post function is:

```
def submit_paste(paste):
    global settings

    data = {
        'title':   settings['title'],
        'name':    settings['author'],
        'text':    paste,
        'lang':    settings['language'],
        'private': settings['private']
    }

    data = bytes(urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode())
    print(data)
    handler = urllib.request.urlopen(settings['url'], data)
    print(handler.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

When I run the script, I get the printed output of data, and the message returned from the API. The data encoding looks correct to me, and outputs:

```
b'private=0&text=hello%2C+world%0A&lang=text&title=Untitled&name=jacob'
```

As you can see, that contains the `text=` attribute, which is the only one actually required for the API call to successfully work. I've been able to successfully post to the API using curl as shown in that link.

The actual error produced by the API is:

> Error: Missing paste text

Is the `text` attribute somehow being encoded incorrectly?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @PaulVirally: Am I doing something wrong with the post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't with the post function, but with the URL. My virtual host automatically forwards `http` traffic to `https`. Apparently, Apache drops the post variables when it forwards.